# Using git behind proxy server

Tags: proxy, git

There are many posts saying to add the proxy credentials to the git config file.

[Getting git to work with a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server/19213999#19213999)

But I think this stores the username and password in clear text in the config file which is not great security plus is a (minor) hassle if your password is changed every 30 days.

How do other organisations get round this - do they host git repositories internally or do the more expensive subscriptions include a way around this? Or a separate proxy server that allows anonymous connections but restricted purely to GitHub IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

So, if you cover how proxy server authentication works from here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Authentication_schemes

You'd see that there are a couple of them which follow certain authorization types:

Here's a quick overview of what's in the link

```
Basic (see RFC 7617, base64-encoded credentials. See below for more information.),
Bearer (see RFC 6750, bearer tokens to access OAuth 2.0-protected resources),
Digest (see RFC 7616, only md5 hashing is supported in Firefox, see bug 472823 for SHA encryption support),
HOBA (see RFC 7486 (draft), HTTP Origin-Bound Authentication, digital-signature-based),
Mutual (see draft-ietf-httpauth-mutual),
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 (see AWS docs).
```

So the config for authentication using Git over a proxy should be Basic which uses Plain-HTTP authentication so that's clear text, hence the purpose of Git using them non-encrypted.

I haven't seen any other use case for the other authentication schemes regarding Git in general. I'd really love to see an example but I haven't discovered such personally.

Since it's basic, then you'd just have to use it as such and update it over every password change cycle or use SSH to prevent using a password in the first place

Comment: Does the Git Credential Manager for Windows help at all? Or does it only store the GitHub credentials and not the AD enterprise ones?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the GIT Credentials Manager on Windows but I do know you can prevent all this by using SSH credentials to access your git server.